# Getting ClassNotFoundException from Activity

Tags: java, android

My application downloads a file from Internet "myJavaObject", stores it on internal storage and go to the following activity if the download finishes with success. This activity throws an exception:"ClassNotFoundException: AJavaObject", but I don't understand why. The downloaded file contains an ArrayList
Who can help me?
Why do i get error on second "usage" of AJavaObject and not the first?

```
public class RetrieveMyJavaObject extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); 

        //NOT HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!  
        ArrayList<AJavaObject> deserialized = new ArrayList<AJavaObject>();
        try{
            FileInputStream inputFileStream = openFileInput("myJavaObjects");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputFileStream);


            //NEXT LINE THROWS EXCEPTION!
            deserialized = (ArrayList<AJavaObject>) objectInputStream.readObject(); 


            objectInputStream.close();
            inputFileStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){Log.e("Error in openFiles",""+e);}  
    }

    class AJavaObject implements Serializable {
        private String firstString;
        private String secondString;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public AJavaObject(String s1, String s2){
             this.firstString=s1; this.secondString=s2;
        }

        public String getFirstString(){ return this.firstString; }
        public String getSecondString(){ return this.secondString; }
    }
}
```

And this is the error log:

```
02-03 18:05:15.283    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AJavaObject
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1784)
02-03 18:05:15.361    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:661)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-03 18:05:15.369    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1985)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at com.testing.anapp.RetrieveMyJavaObject.onCreate(RetrieveMyJavaObject.java:6)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 18:05:15.376    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: AJavaObject
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ ... 33 more
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "AJavaObject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testing.anapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.testing.anapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-03 18:05:15.384    6607-6607/com.testing.anapp W/System.err﹕ ... 33 more
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log?

Comment: Is there a syntax error in AJavaObject? Your secondString assignment in the constructor is missing a semicolon, or is that just a mistake on the question?

Comment: Sorry, the semicolon is a typo (that i corrected).

Comment: It's not relevant "public" because is the same class: however i tryed also with "public" without results

Comment: How are you serializing the object? If the fully qualified names aren't the same, it will think it's a different object.

Comment: Also, you don't get an error on the first "usage" because that's not actually a usage.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html to learn about Type Erasure with Java generics

Comment: if i do "new RetrieveMyJavaObject.new AJavaObject ("a","b").getClass().getName()" to get fully qualified name i get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AJavaObject". What am i  missing?

Comment: Have you tried just doing a simple project clean?

Comment: Thanks to all, Chris Thompson's comment was the right answer. Fully qualified name was different because the package name.